# Changing one line in code to Traditional Form?

Tags: notebooks

I was watching this video: [Animating Heat Equation](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=250&v=675). The speaker had this code (just prior to the 60 second time level):

```
sol = NDSolve[{
   D[u[t, x, y], t] == D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y],
   u[0, x, y] == 0,
   u[t, x, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 0, y] == Sin[t],
   u[t, x, 5] == 0, u[t, 5, y] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

Then I saw him sort of place his cursor near the end of the second line and I could not quite understand what he said, and suddenly, just the second line turned into I think what is called Traditional Form? Looked like this:

[image]

I tried selecting the whole cell then selecting Traditional Form (Cell->Convert To->Traditional Form) from the menu, but it looked like this:

[image]

Any thoughts on how he did this? Might be because the video was in 2012?

Comment: It's StandardForm. Use the menu item Cell > Convert To > StandardForm, or the keyboard shortcut listed there.

Comment: What he says in the video is that he used Shift-Control-N to convert to `StandardForm` because that's more readable. It can also be done by going to the `Cell` menu. Ah I just saw @SimonRochester posted the same thing... But the command acts on the whole cell, not a single line. I don't think you can have a code cell where only one line is in `TraditionalForm` and the rest aren't.

Comment: @SimonRochester and Jens, Yep, my bad. It works fine when you do StandardForm. Thanks.

Comment: @Everybody This rises an interesting question: Is it possible to transform the input expression into the TraditionalForm upon placing a cursor on it, such that it transforms back upon its removal? Indeed, this might be very useful during Mma lecturing for new users.

Comment: @Jens Why not to formulate this as a regular answer? I find it to be of use and not that trivial to leave it as a comment.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Indeed - since nobody proposed to close the question, your assessment is probably correct.

Comment: @Alexei Why don't you post that "interesting question" separately?  I can imagine the value in that, and I'll take a shot at if no one else does.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard Done

Answer (score 4):

What he says in the video is that he used <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to convert to StandardForm because that's more readable. (On Mac, replace <kbd>Control</kbd> by <kbd>Command</kbd>). It can also be done by going to the `Cell` menu and choosing "Convert To... > StandardForm". If you want `TraditionalForm`, the <kbd>N</kbd> key is replaced by <kbd>T</kbd>.

But the command acts on the whole cell, not a single line. In an Input cell, you **can** convert a sub-expression to `TraditionalForm` by selecting it and using the same shortcut as above. But this isn't based on  **lines**; it's based on having a parseable (sub-)**expression**. If your selection is of that type, its converted form will retain all the information necessary to bring it back to `InputForm` or any other form because it's accompanied by an invisible `TemplateBox`.

In any case, such parseable subexpressions can be broken up into several lines, and then it would not in general be possible to convert a single line by itself.