# Jumping between the InputForm and TraditionalForm during Presentation

Tags: slideshows, traditional-form, input-forms

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88433/changing-one-line-in-code-to-traditional-form?noredirect=1#comment241438_88433) a problem has been discussed of how to transform a cell from Input into, say, TraditionalForm within the notebook.

There is a related problem of how one could to do that on the screen in a classroom. That is, in the Presentation mode.It seems me useful to be able to change from the InputForm to, say, TraditionalForm upon placing the cursor over the line and simultaneously pressing, say, Ctrl key. The Ctrl key would ensure that the code will not change its form, if I want to enter the line (then without Ctrl) to just add something to it.

It is a bit too luxurious, of course, but it  might help in the classroom for students who are not that familiar with Mma yet to faster understand the code. In that case it might be of some use, if its realization is not too complex.

Comment: It seems like the simplest method would be to use Control-Shift-T to convert to TraditionalForm, and Control-Z to switch back.

Comment: @ Simon Rochester Yes, this is the possibility, but during the lecture it is not convenient. The question is how to do this with the cursor.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @SimonRochester because the keyboard is faster. The only disadvantage I can see is that viewers of the screen presentation can't see *what you did* to make the change, if it's solely done by keyboard. So maybe one could use a palette instead, so people can see when you're activating it. Is that what you're thinking about?